# How to prove that $f$ has a zero

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:B(x_0;r)\subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism from $B(x_0;r)$ to $f(B(x_0;r))$. If $\|f'(x)^{-1}\|\le M$ for all $x \in B(x_0;r)$ and $|f(x_0)| < r/M$, we have to show that $f$ has at least one zero. I tried to show that, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0 \in B(y_0;\delta)$ and $B(y_0;\delta) \subset f(B(x_0,r))$, where $y_0 = f(x_0)$. But, I can't show that $0 \in B(y_0;\delta)$. Should I use the Inverse Function Theorem?

Comment: I think you have to use that $1=\|f'(x)\|\|f'(x)\|\leq M\|f'(x)\|$ so that the ball of centre $x_0$ is mapped to a set containing another ball and hopefully the condition on $|f(x_0)|$ allows to deduce $0$ belongs to the image

Comment: @WilliamM. I didn't get it :/ How can I assume that the ball of center $x_0$ is mapped to a set containing another ball?

Comment: Because the (operator) norm of the derivative is at least a constant. This intuitively says that it is at least that constant times the identity.

Comment: @WilliamM. I'll think about it! Thanks

Comment: Does $f'$ denote the Jacobian of $f$? Which norm $\lVert - \rvert$ do you use for matrices? And is $\lvert - \rvert$ the Euclidean norm?

Comment: @PaulFrost, $f'$ is the derivative of $f$, and $|\cdot|$ could be the Euclidean norm. But for me, there is no difference about which norm we're going to use

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta Of course all norms are equivalent. But $B(x_0;r)$ certainly denotes an Euclidean ball, thus it is nikot completely irrelevant. And if you take $M = \sup \lVert f'(x)^{-1} \rVert$, it is not at all irrelevant which norms you take for $\lVert - \rVert$ and in $|f(x_0)| < r/M$.

Comment: @PaulFrost but in this exercise, there is no specification